# I am trying to read in a file in lua but get the error 'attempt to call global 'pathForFile' (a nil value)'

Tags: lua

I am attempting to read in a data file in lua using Lua Development Tools (eclipse).

I have tried a number of approaches, and seem to always get the same error.  I defined the path using a system call and got an exception because of an "attempt to call global 'pathForFile', which is the function call I found in a Corona post. I have found other references to pathForFile that weren't in the Corona environment so think it is included in LUA absent Corona.  I freely and openly admit I don't know anything about the Corona SDK, outside of references to it while searching for a solution to this problem.

Next, again based on searches for solutions, tried to use the require feature as explained in Chapter 8 of "Programming in Lua".  No joy.  I did get the require feature to look, but the particular file I am using is a .dat file, and I never did get it to see the file.

So, here is where I currently am (code posted below):

```
local path = pathForFile("lab_test.DAT",[[C:\users\gec16a\documents\lab_test.DAT]])

function file_exists(path)

local f = io.open(path/lab_test.DAT,"rb")

if f then f:close()
end
return f ~= nil
 end
```

I am still receiving an exception code that I will list below:

> Exception in thread "main" com.naef.jnlua.LuaRuntimeException: ...t-win32.win32.x86_64\workspace\training\src\main.lua:18: attempt to call global >'pathForFile' (a nil value)
>     at com.naef.jnlua.LuaState.lua_pcall(Native Method)
>     at com.naef.jnlua.LuaState.call(LuaState.java:555)
>     at org.eclipse.ldt.support.lua51.internal.interpreter.JNLua51Launcher.run(JNLua51L>auncher.java:128)
>     at org.eclipse.ldt.support.lua51.internal.interpreter.JNLua51DebugLauncher.main(JN>Lua51DebugLauncher.java:24)

Thanks in advance for any suggestions and directions!

Code and console after adding local system = require("system")

```
function main()

  local system = require("system")

  local path = system.pathForFile("lab_test.DAT", [[C:\users\gec16a\documents\]])

  function file_exists(path)

    local f = io.open(path/lab_test.DAT,"rb")

    if f then f:close()
    end
    return f ~= nil
  end
end

main()
```

Console output:
Debugger v1.3.1
Debugger: Trying to connect to 127.0.0.1:10000 ... 
Debugger: Connection succeed.
Exception in thread "main" com.naef.jnlua.LuaRuntimeException: ...t-win32.win32.x86_64\workspace\training\src\main.lua:6: module 'system' not found:
    no field package.preload['system']
    no file '.\system.lua'
    no file 'C:\Program Files\Java\jre1.8.0_92\bin\lua\system.lua'
    no file 'C:\Program Files\Java\jre1.8.0_92\bin\lua\system\init.lua'
    no file 'C:\Program Files\Java\jre1.8.0_92\bin\system.lua'
    no file 'C:\Program Files\Java\jre1.8.0_92\bin\system\init.lua'
    no file 'C:\Users\gec16a\Downloads\org.eclipse.ldt.product-win32.win32.x86_64\workspace\training\src\system.lua'
    no file 'C:\Users\gec16a\Downloads\org.eclipse.ldt.product-win32.win32.x86_64\workspace\training\src\system\init.lua'
    no file 'C:\Users\gec16a\Downloads\org.eclipse.ldt.product-win32.win32.x86_64\workspace\training\src\system.luac'
    no file 'C:\Users\gec16a\Downloads\org.eclipse.ldt.product-win32.win32.x86_64\workspace\training\src\system\init.luac'
    no file 'C:\Program Files (x86)\eclipse\Lua\configuration\org.eclipse.osgi\179\0.cp\script\external\system.lua'
    no file 'C:\Program Files (x86)\eclipse\Lua\configuration\org.eclipse.osgi\179\0.cp\script\external\system\init.lua'
    no file 'C:\Program Files (x86)\eclipse\Lua\configuration\org.eclipse.osgi\179\0.cp\script\external\system.luac'
    no file 'C:\Program Files (x86)\eclipse\Lua\configuration\org.eclipse.osgi\179\0.cp\script\external\system\init.luac'
    no file 'C:\Program Files (x86)\eclipse\Lua\configuration\org.eclipse.osgi\179\0.cp\script\internal\system.lua'
    no file 'C:\Program Files (x86)\eclipse\Lua\configuration\org.eclipse.osgi\179\0.cp\script\internal\system\init.lua'
    no file 'C:\Program Files (x86)\eclipse\Lua\configuration\org.eclipse.osgi\179\0.cp\script\internal\system.luac'
    no file 'C:\Program Files (x86)\eclipse\Lua\configuration\org.eclipse.osgi\179\0.cp\script\internal\system\init.luac'
    no file '.\system.dll'
    no file '.\system51.dll'
    no file 'C:\Program Files\Java\jre1.8.0_92\bin\system.dll'
    no file 'C:\Program Files\Java\jre1.8.0_92\bin\system51.dll'
    no file 'C:\Program Files\Java\jre1.8.0_92\bin\clibs\system.dll'
    no file 'C:\Program Files\Java\jre1.8.0_92\bin\clibs\system51.dll'
    no file 'C:\Program Files\Java\jre1.8.0_92\bin\loadall.dll'
    no file 'C:\Program Files\Java\jre1.8.0_92\bin\clibs\loadall.dll'
    at com.naef.jnlua.LuaState.lua_pcall(Native Method)
    at com.naef.jnlua.LuaState.call(LuaState.java:555)
    at org.eclipse.ldt.support.lua51.internal.interpreter.JNLua51Launcher.run(JNLua51Launcher.java:128)
    at org.eclipse.ldt.support.lua51.internal.interpreter.JNLua51DebugLauncher.main(JNLua51DebugLauncher.java:24)

Update: I was missing a system.dll file that was in a Microsoft folder.  I copied it over to my lua folder.  I now get the below error message:

Exception in thread "main" com.naef.jnlua.LuaRuntimeException: ...t-win32.win32.x86_64\workspace\training\src\main.lua:10: attempt to index global 'system' (a nil value)
    at com.naef.jnlua.LuaState.lua_pcall(Native Method)
    at com.naef.jnlua.LuaState.call(LuaState.java:555)
    at org.eclipse.ldt.support.lua51.internal.interpreter.JNLua51Launcher.run(JNLua51Launcher.java:128)
    at org.eclipse.ldt.support.lua51.internal.interpreter.JNLua51Launcher.main(JNLua51Launcher.java:143)

Comment: I was downvoted on this post, but not sure why.  I provided all of the information I have.  Did I miss something?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`system` isn't a module (by default). Also, you need to pass a string to `io`, rather than raw code that just equates to `path` divided by the `DAT` index of a table called `lab_test`. You should read the [5.1 reference manual](http://www.lua.org/manual/5.1/manual.html) to get documentation on what is actually available by default. This seems like what you want:

```
local file, err = io.open("C:\users\gec16a\documents\lab_test.DAT", "rb")
if file then
    -- use file
else
    -- optional, `err` will be a string with an error message
end
```

Comment: Thank you!  I had pretty much given up on an answer after getting hit with downvotes.  I still don't quite understand why, I had given it a go and could think of no other choice.  Thanks again for your solution and  your explanation!